# How to decode this PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to decode this "fast". I do understand how the code works, 5=e etc, but I will have to recode my changes back so I was wondering if anyone knew how to decode this with some kind of web tool ? Maybe ?

```
    ?><?php
/**
 * Th5 t5mpl1t5 f2r d4spl1y4ng th5 f22t5r.
 *
 * C2nt14ns th5 cl2s4ng 2f th5 4d=p1g5 d4v 1nd 1ll c2nt5nt 1ft5r
 *
 * @p1ck1g5 W2rdPr5ss
 */
?>

    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #p1g5-4nn5r -->
    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #p1g5 -->
    <!-- END PAGE -->

    <?php g5t_t5mpl1t5_p1rt( 'b2tt2m-m5n3' ); // o-C2l3mn B2tt2m M5n3 (b2tt2m-m5n3.php) ?>

    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <d4v 4d="f22t5r">
    <d4v 4d="f22t5r-4nn5r" cl1ss="cl51rf4x">

        <d4v 4d="f22t5r-l5ft">
            <p>Th5m5 by <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/" t4tl5="B5st SUV">B5st SUV</1><br />
            <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/f35l-5ff4c45nt-s3vs/" t4tl5="F35l Eff4c45nt SUVs">F35l Eff4c45nt SUVs</1> | <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/k41-s3v/" t4tl5="K41 SUV">K41 SUV</1> | <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/bmw-s3v/bmw-xe-m/" t4tl5="BMW Xe M">BMW Xe M</1></p>
        </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r-l5ft -->

        <d4v 4d="f22t5r-r4ght">
            <p>&c2py; <?php 5ch2 d1t5('Y');?> <1 hr5f="<?php bl2g4nf2('s4t53rl');?>/" t4tl5="<?php bl2g4nf2('n1m5');?>" ><?php bl2g4nf2('n1m5');?></1></p>
        </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r-r4ght -->

    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r-4nn5r -->
    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r -->
    <!-- END FOOTER -->

</d4v> <!-- 5nd wr1pp5r -->

<?php wp_f22t5r(); ?>

</b2dy>
</html
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple to do on the commandline:

```
cat script.php | tr 12345 aouie
```

But that will obviously just replace the characters without looking at context. So certainly lead to buggy results. Might only work on that small snippet.

There are no automated tools for custom leetspeak encodings like that. How that invalid HTML is supposed to work is beyond me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just lower-case vowels are being replaced.

```
1=a
2=o
3=u
4=i
5=e
```

Just search and replace in your text editor, so that you can look at context (i.e. that it really isn't intended to be a number 1-5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = <<<html
<?php
/**
 * Th5 t5mpl1t5 f2r d4spl1y4ng th5 f22t5r.
 *
 * C2nt14ns th5 cl2s4ng 2f th5 4d=p1g5 d4v 1nd 1ll c2nt5nt 1ft5r
 *
 * @p1ck1g5 W2rdPr5ss
 */
?>

    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #p1g5-4nn5r -->
    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #p1g5 -->
    <!-- END PAGE -->

    <?php g5t_t5mpl1t5_p1rt( 'b2tt2m-m5n3' ); // o-C2l3mn B2tt2m M5n3 (b2tt2m-m5n3.php) ?>

    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <d4v 4d="f22t5r">
    <d4v 4d="f22t5r-4nn5r" cl1ss="cl51rf4x">

        <d4v 4d="f22t5r-l5ft">
            <p>Th5m5 by <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/" t4tl5="B5st SUV">B5st SUV</1><br />
            <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/f35l-5ff4c45nt-s3vs/" t4tl5="F35l Eff4c45nt SUVs">F35l Eff4c45nt SUVs</1> | <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/k41-s3v/" t4tl5="K41 SUV">K41 SUV</1> | <1 hr5f="http://s3v.r5v45w4t2nl4n5.n5t/bmw-s3v/bmw-xe-m/" t4tl5="BMW Xe M">BMW Xe M</1></p>
        </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r-l5ft -->

        <d4v 4d="f22t5r-r4ght">
            <p>&c2py; <?php 5ch2 d1t5('Y');?> <1 hr5f="<?php bl2g4nf2('s4t53rl');?>/" t4tl5="<?php bl2g4nf2('n1m5');?>" ><?php bl2g4nf2('n1m5');?></1></p>
        </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r-r4ght -->

    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r-4nn5r -->
    </d4v> <!-- 5nd d4v #f22t5r -->
    <!-- END FOOTER -->

</d4v> <!-- 5nd wr1pp5r -->

<?php wp_f22t5r(); ?>

</b2dy>
</html>
html;

$find    = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$replace = array('a','o','u','i','e');
echo highlight_string(str_replace($find,$replace,$str),true);
```

Result:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=page div and all content after
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
?>

    </div> <!-- end div #page-inner -->
    </div> <!-- end div #page -->
    <!-- END PAGE -->

    <?php get_template_part( 'bottom-menu' ); // o-Column Bottom Menu (bottom-menu.php) ?>

    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inner" class="clearfix">

        <div id="footer-left">
            <p>Theme by <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/" title="Best SUV">Best SUV</a><br />
            <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/fuel-efficient-suvs/" title="Fuel Efficient SUVs">Fuel Efficient SUVs</a> | <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/kia-suv/" title="Kia SUV">Kia SUV</a> | <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/bmw-suv/bmw-xe-m/" title="BMW Xe M">BMW Xe M</a></p>
        </div> <!-- end div #footer-left -->

        <div id="footer-right">
            <p>&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name');?>" ><?php bloginfo('name');?></a></p>
        </div> <!-- end div #footer-right -->

    </div> <!-- end div #footer-inner -->
    </div> <!-- end div #footer -->
    <!-- END FOOTER -->

</div> <!-- end wrapper -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```